Navigating to third view after launch pops back
So I have been stuck for a two days with swiftui navigation. I have viewA which navigates to viewB and viewB to viewC right after launch. The issue is, when I navigate to the third view right after launch, the third view gets dismissed. I tried stuff like adding .stack view style, .isDetailLink, embedding empty navigation links, using UIKit onAppear, to delay navigation and so on so on but nothing helped. I found out if I add for eg. 5s delay, it works fine. Sometimes it navigates even without the delay as it should, but sometimes its not working. Here is the sample code:
struct viewA: View {
    @State var viewIsActive: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink("", destination: viewB(), isActive: $viewIsActive)
                .isDetailLink(false) // option 1
        }
    }
}
struct viewB: View {
    @State var viewIsActive: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            NavigationLink("", destination: viewC(), isActive: $viewIsActive)
        }
    }
}
struct viewC: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
        }
    }
}

Important note is this issue is being caused on iPhone 12Pro (iOS 16.0 and 15.0), different devices such as iPhone 14Pro etc. are working fine. I found iPhone 12Pro with iOS 16 and 15 really unreliable in regard to dev.
Anybody knows?

NavigationView is a bit broken and was replaced with NavigationStack so you could try that along with NavigationPath.
